# Grouping and summing two SQL tables, and replacing missing values

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by

I have the following table "persons":

```
|    id   |  name   | 
| ------  |  -----  |
|    1    |  Adam   |  
|    2    |  Nick   |
|    3    |  John   |
```

Another table "amounts":

```
id  amount  month  customerid
 1   500    Jan      1
 2   1000   Feb      1
 3   1200   Jan      1
 4   700    Jan      2
 5   400    Feb      2
 6   210    Jan      null
 7   230    Feb      null
```

where persons.id corresponds to amounts.customerid

How do I return a sql query that returns the amount generated per person in January, with the name for a null customerid being "Unknown"?

```
|   name  |  value  | 
| ------  |  -----  |
|   Adam  |  1700   |  
|   Nick  |  700    |
|   John  |  0      |
| Unknown |  210    |
```

Comment: Names and values are poor table names.Persons (or perhaps customers) is a better table name. Also, value is a poor column name. Value of what?

Comment: Do an outer join. group by.

Comment: edited the table names.

Comment: @jarlh I'm trying to work with this example on sqlite, where outer joins aren't supported. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: You should mention/tag the SQL dialect you use. Here's a pointer if it's Oracle : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/null-related-functions

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/

Answer (score 0):

Without LEFT JOIN, you can do it in two steps. First JOIN and aggregate for the known persons. Then add the unknowns.

```
select p.name, sum(a.amount)
from amounts a
join persons p on a.customerid = p.id
where a.month = 'Jan'
group by p.name

union all

select 'Unknown', sum(amount)
from amounts
where a.month = 'Jan' and customerid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a LEFT JOIN and `COALESCE()` will do the trick here:

```
SELECT COAELSCE(persons.name, 'Unknown') as personname, sum(amount) sumamount
FROM  amounts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN person ON amounts.customerid = persons.id
GROUP BY COALESCE(persons.name, 'Unknown')
WHERE month = 'Jan';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement could be solved with a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but SQLite does not support it.
So instead you can use `UNION ALL` for table `persons` to include a row with a `null` id and then a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select p.name, coalesce(sum(a.value), 0) value 
from (select * from persons union all select null, 'Unknown') p 
left join (select * from amounts where month = 'Jan') a
on (p.id = a.customerid) or (p.id is null and a.customerid is null)
where p.id is not null or a.value is not null
group by p.id, p.name
order by p.name is null, p.name
```

The condition:

```
where p.id is not null or a.value is not null
```

makes sure that if there are no `customerid`s with `null` then in the results there will be no row with name `'Unknown'` with `value = 0`.
 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iMXZnvDssjpGRtYQG9Vjtv/5).
Results:

```
| name    | value |
| ------- | ----- |
| Adam    | 1700  |
| Nick    | 700   |
| John    | 0     |
| Unknown | 210   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you want is a full join between the tables.  Sadly, SQLite does not support `FULL JOIN`.

There are different ways to emulate the solution.  For this particular case, though, I think it is sufficient to use a `LEFT JOIN` to get all the persons.  And then `UNION ALL` to bring in the unknowns:

```
select p.name, coalesce(sum(a.value), 0) value 
from persons p left join
     amounts a
     on a.customerid = p.id and
        a.month = 'Jan'
group by p.name
union all
select 'Unknown', sum(a.value)
from amounts a
where a.customerid is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fa8b24759cea4989171fa13635b2ca18) is a db<>fiddle.

The first query brings in all customers, using `left join`, even those with no amounts.  The second brings in the "unknown".